# Laravel error display html code instead of rendering it (debug mode ON)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

When an error occur in DEBUG mode on laravel 4.2, i got the error displayed but in full plain text (with the html code in it).

as you can see on this image
[image]

then i have to search every time for "stacktrace" on the page to see the error :

[image]

It should display errors like on this link bellow
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/2013/06/whoops-laravel.png

I don't get it, i spent like 2 days trying to fix this but nothing works..

I just saw that the debug bar is not rendered too but it is in the html code as well.

When i create a view in App::error, i don't have problems, but this is not what i want, i would like the fancy display you saw on my previous link which is the one that laravel use by default in debug mode..

Comment: are you using blade template ?

Comment: is the extension of the view file is like   filename.blade    ?  or u just using filename.php

Comment: there is no view file, if i make a view in the  App::error, it will render my view but it will not use the  "whoops" package, and if i don't make a view, whoops is used but not rendered well

Comment: make sure HTML service provide is install. 

find the below line in app.php in config folder. if it is there


  'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey so i posted on the GIT of Whoops, and i got the right answer to my problem..

i simply had to add

`header('Content-Type: text/html');`

So simple.. but yet i didn't thought of this